# Slather command failed to execute. Xcode, Jenkins, Sonar qube

Tags: xcode, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, slather

```
+ slather coverage --binary-basename Project --input-format profdata -i '.*Tests.*' --cobertura-xml --output-directory sonar-reports --workspace Project.xcworkspace --scheme ProjectTests Project.xcodeproj
ERROR: Unrecognised option '--workspace'

See: 'slather coverage --help'

+ returnValue=1

+ set +x

ERROR - Command 'slather coverage --binary-basename Project --input-format profdata -i .*Tests.* --cobertura-xml --output-directory sonar-reports --workspace Project.xcworkspace --scheme ProjectTests Project.xcodeproj' 

failed with error code: 1
```

Parameters which I have specified as follows.

```
workspaceFile=''; readParameter workspaceFile 'sonar.swift.workspace'

slatherCmd+=( --input-format profdata $excludedCommandLineFlags --cobertura-xml --output-directory sonar-reports)

if [[ ! -z "$workspaceFile" ]]; then
    echo "$workspaceFile"
    slatherCmd+=( --workspace $workspaceFile)
```

In the sonar project.properties I have mentioned the workspace.

Getting this error while working with Xcode, Jenkins, and Sonar Qube.
What could be wrong with the command? Did I miss something?
Slather is installed in mac, is there something that I have to set up before running Xcode?

I tried installing Slather but I don't know why it is showing that.

Comment: did you get solution for it